# Problem with vertical line in vs code indentation

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, settings, vertical-alignment, indentation

I have this problem: I'm using Vue CLI with Vetur/Volar, and as u can see from the pic, i wish i could see indentation line also between the empty spaces. Vs code automatically indent everything like that by itself in my case, but, with some empty spaces without lines. And (more strange) i have in my project only 'one' file (a FooterPage.vue file as all the other .vue, nothing different) that's indent in the correct way....only in that file... I actually decided to remove indentation line because is frustrating
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjuNq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJIjW.png)

I need the Indentation lines like the Footer vue file from the system and not like the other pic

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your user settings.json or your workspace's `.vscode/settings.json` file:

```json
"[css]": {
    "editor.indentSize": 3,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false
}
```